# Why does my boolean function sometimes return None?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-3.x, functional-programming

Using Python 3.4. Have attempted to call function prime/2 that returns a boolean--always either True or False--from within an IF-statement. The function is expensive to run, so I want to call it only when I know it is needed, hence calling from within a decision point. The called function does not reliably return True/False. Sometimes the return is None, at which point the test fails. I use Python's IDLE and its debugger. I call primes(2, 5, []) and step through the code. When prime/2 reaches line elif n <= p while n = 5 and p = 5, the debugger shows that prime/2 returns True, as it should, but the line in primes/3 elif prime(m, 2) takes a value of None. And at that point my test fails. My code:

```
def primes(m, n, l):        # the calling function
    if m > n:               # creates a list of primes from
        print(l, end='\n')  # m through n, inclusive
    elif m < 2:
        primes(2, n, l)
    elif m == 2:
        l.append(2)
        primes(3, n, l)
    elif m % 2 == 0:
        primes(m + 1, n, l)
    elif prime(m, 2):        # calling the second function
        l.append(m)          # to test m for primality
        primes(m + 2, n, l)
    else:
        primes(m + 2, n, l)

def prime(n, p):             # the called function will return
    if n < 2:                # True if m is prime, False otherwise
        return False
    elif n < 4:
        return True
    elif n <= p:
        return True
    elif (n > 2) and (n % p == 0):
        return False
    elif p == 2:
        prime(n, 3)
    else:
        prime(n, p + 2)
```

Comment: please show your code so we know what you're talking about

Comment: _"The reference manual syntax disallows what I'm trying to do within the IF"_. You're saying that `if myFunctionCall():` doesn't work for you? That's perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: Python short circuits out of boolean expressions.  Although it's hard to tell exactly without your code, but something like `if need_time_consuming_func and time_consuming_func():` will not call time_consuming_func() if `need_time_consuming_func` is False.

Comment: Python3.x Reference Manual. My understanding of what I read is that the IF condition can be (1) an equivalence test such as ==, \=, <, etc. or (2) a lambda statement. Yes, I agree, if myFunctionCall(): is valid in other languages.

Comment: I'll provide some code. Just have to figure out how that's done.

Comment: You can make a code block by indenting four spaces, or you can surround a code snippet with ` (back tic) characters.

Comment: I'm looking at the Python reference manual, too. The [reference for `if` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) is, `if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite ( "elif" expression ":" suite )* ["else" ":" suite]`. That first "expression" means you can put _any_ expression after the if, not just binary operator expressions and lambda expressions. Maybe you were looking at "Conditional expressions", which is something different.

Comment: `
def primes(m, n, l):
    if m > n:
        print(l, end='\n')
    elif m < 2:
        primes(2, n, l)
    elif m == 2:
        l.append(2)
        primes(3, n, l)
    elif m % 2 == 0:
        primes(m + 1, n, l)
    else:
     a = prime(m, 2)
     if a:
         l.append(m)
         primes(m + 2, n, l)
     else:
         primes(m + 2, n, l)

def prime(n, p):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    elif n < 4:
        return True
    elif n <= p:
        return True
    elif (n > 2) and (n % p == 0):
        return False
    elif p == 2:
        prime(n, 3)
    else:
        prime(n, p + 2)
`

Comment: Add the code to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Not able to get code entered in a readable fashion. Ah, thank you.

Comment: [Use this link to edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27570915/edit); it can also be found in small grey text underneath your question, near the tags.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code :-) Did you say it was causing a Syntax Error? I ran them and I didn't get any Syntax Errors.

Comment: No, I did refer to reference manual and syntax, but this code doesn't produce syntax errors. Line 13: a = prime(m, 2) doesn't always assign a True/False value to a. Sometimes a is assigned a value of None, at which point the test fails.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is better described as "Why does my Boolean function sometimes return None?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in how you call prime() recursively. You need to explicitly return the value. Like this:

```
def prime(n, p):             # the called function will return
    if n < 2:                # True if m is prime, False otherwise
        return False
    elif n < 4:
        return True
    elif n <= p:
        return True
    elif (n > 2) and (n % p == 0):
        return False
    elif p == 2:
        return prime(n, 3)   # <--- RETURN VALUE
    return prime(n, p + 2)   # <--- & RETURN VALUE
```

Comment: Yes, I've verified that this works. Thank you so much.

Comment: no problem. if you feel this solves the question, the stackoverflow procedure is to mark this as the answer.